# What's the difference between CreationPolicy and DependsOn attributes in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Can someone explain the difference between CreationPolicy and DependsOn attributes in CloudFormation with an easy to understand example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are few. The key are:

- [CreationPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-creationpolicy.html) only applies to **three resources** (AutoScalingGroup, Instance, and WaitCondition), while [DependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) can be used on **any resource**.
- Primary purpose of `CreationPolicy` is to **wait for "signals"** from instances. When you create an instance using CFN, you can add your bootstrap scripts to `User Data`. For example, install some packages, setup some config files. CFN does not check if the bootstrap script execute successful. This is problematic, because your **bootstrap script may fail**, and you will not know about this until too late. To overcome this issue you can add  `CreationPolicy` to the instance so that it waits for [cfn-signal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-signal.html) from the instance. With this, your bootstrap script can signal to CFN that the script executed successful.
- Primary purpose of `DependsOn` is relative **ordering of resource creation** in CFN. By its nature, CFN attempts to creates resources in parallel. This can lead to issues, if for example your instance requires some other resource to be created beforehand (e.g. RDS database). In this case, you can tell CFN to create the instance only after the RDS database was successfully created.

Answer (score 2):

CREATION POLICY:

Creation policy attribute is used when u want a resource to prevent its status from reaching create complete until your CFN receives a certain number of signals or a timeout period is exceeded. Usually its used when your using a userdata to install something on your EC2 Instance.

To signal a resource, you can use the cfn-signal helper script or SignalResource API. AWS CloudFormation publishes valid signals to the stack events so that you track the number of signals sent.

Currently, the only AWS CloudFormation resources that support creation policies are

```
AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
AWS::EC2::Instance
AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition.
```

For example, if you install and configure software applications on an EC2 instance, you might want those applications to be running before proceeding. In such cases, you can add a CreationPolicy attribute to the instance, and then send a success signal to the instance after the applications are installed and configured.

The below example will not create the resource Autoscaling until it receives 3 signals from the cfn-signal.

```
"AutoScalingGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "AvailabilityZones": { "Fn::GetAZs": "" },
    "LaunchConfigurationName": { "Ref": "LaunchConfig" },
    "DesiredCapacity": "3",
    "MinSize": "1",
    "MaxSize": "4"
  },
  "CreationPolicy": {
    "ResourceSignal": {
      "Count": "3",
      "Timeout": "PT15M"
    }
  }
 }
},
"LaunchConfig": {
  "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
  "Properties": {
    "ImageId": "ami-16d18a7e",
    "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
    "UserData": {
      "Fn::Base64": {
        "Fn::Join" : [ "", [
          "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
          "yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",
          "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e 0 --stack ", { "Ref": "AWS::StackName" },
          " --resource AutoScalingGroup ",
          " --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
        ] ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

DEPENDS ON

With the DependsOn attribute you can specify that the creation of a specific resource follows another. When you add a DependsOn attribute to a resource, that resource is created only after the creation of the resource specified in the DependsOn attribute.

This can be used:

1. When you want to declare a dependencies for a resources to be created or deleted in a specific order.
2. Override default parallelism.